# Android L Raised Normal Button

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop

I've been hunting high and low for a way to get a "raised" rounded rectangular button without completely doing it myself using backgrounds and a custom view. I want buttons like this:

[image]

I thought this would do it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter the Danger Zone"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:elevation="8dp" <!-- Here -->
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But this does nothing. The button looks the same. WTF?

And yes, I'm using the latest SDK, etc. etc.

Edit:
So I added a translationZ. Now, a shadow appears as the activity is opening, but disappears when the animation is done. ???

Comment: My apologies for my earlier comment -- I was interrupted and couldn't complete it. What I was aiming for was that `android:elevation` *should* be controlling this, and I was going to ask if you were using `appcompat-v7` or the native API Level 21 `Theme.Material` and kin. However, I can reproduce your problem using `Theme.Material.Light`, and I can't explain it.

Comment: Should it work in appcompat-v7?

Comment: In theory, yes, but, in theory, it should be working now. I have asked [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button), using the `ElevationBasic` SDK sample, which also exhibits this apparently-broken behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding state list animator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="8dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
<item>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="2dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: like so: <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@anim/btn_anim</item>
(or directly on your button, if you're not using styles).

Comment: However, I hope there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: @Charles: `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` will remove the stock `StateListAnimator`, allowing `android:elevation` to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem i thought was due to wrongly inflated layouts, but it appeared that adding clipToPadding did the trick.
This must be set to the parent ViewGroup containing the view you want to cast a shadow.

```
<YourParentLayout
...
android:clipToPadding="false"
...
```

also if your view has no background, use `android:outlineProvider="bounds"`