# Android 5.0 android:elevation Works for View, but not Button?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In the Android 5.0 samples from the SDK Manager, there is the `ElevationBasic` sample. It shows two `View` objects: a circle and a square. The circle has `android:elevation` set to `30dp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright 2014 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
            android:id="@+id/floating_shape"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:elevation="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/floating_shape_2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

On a Nexus 9, running the sample as-is, we get a drop shadow on the circle:

[image: ElevationBasic, As Originally Written]

If we change the widget class to `Button`, leaving all other attributes as-is, we lose the drop shadow on the circle:

[image: ElevationBasic, Using a Button]

The questions:

1. Why is the `android:elevation` behavior changing? It cannot be due to the background, because it is the same background in both cases.
2. Which classes support `android:elevation`, and which do not? For example, using `TextView` instead of `View` or `Button` still gives us the drop shadow, so this change in behavior is not introduced at the `TextView` level, but rather at the `Button` level.
3. As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070436/android-l-raised-normal-button) from yesterday, how do we get `android:elevation` to be honored on a `Button`? Is there some `android:allowElevationToWorkAsDocumented="true"` value that we have to put in a theme or something?

Comment: Intresting question and findings, any change you would be able to share the test project with us?

Comment: @Rolfツ: Again, it is the `ElevationBasic` sample from the Android 5.0 samples, that you can download from the SDK Manager. I did not write the sample, though I amended it as noted in the question for `Button` test.

Comment: My bad, I read it a bit to fast ;)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The default Button style under Material has a [StateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html) that controls the `android:elevation` and `android:translationZ` properties. You can remove the existing animator or set your own using the `android:stateListAnimator` property.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@null" />

<Button
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/my_animator" />
```

The default animator is defined in [button_state_list_anim_material.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/anim/button_state_list_anim_material.xml). Here is a sample showing the enabled and pressed states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                            android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_pressed_z_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                            android:duration="0"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    <!-- base state -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                            android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                            android:valueTo="0"
                            android:startDelay="@integer/button_pressed_animation_delay"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                            android:duration="0"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    ...
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks! This made it possible for a flat button to look the same with pre-L devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare hi i used this but its not showing shadow any help?

Comment: Dude you saved my life, by using  android:stateListAnimator="@null" I was fixed all problems with z-order

Comment: That animator rewriting these values is so wrong on so many levels... :( Developers are totally left in the dark wondering why has the button different elevation or z translation

Answer (score 13):

In my experience with Appcompat v7 running on Lollipop device, `Button` works with default features as ripple effect, elevation and z-animation on click, but misses them if is set a personalized `android:background` property (as color or selector) in xml element.

Comment: This question is about the native Android 5.0 implementation, not `appcompat-v7`. Thanks, though!

Comment: maybe the same, appcompat v7 inherits styles from Material through Platform theme if is running on Android 5.

Comment: Same here, if someone knows the answer, it would be helpful !

Answer (score 7):

This is because you are setting the background of the button manually which will replace all its effects.

As of the version **23.0.0** release of **AppCompat**, there is a new **Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored** style which uses your theme's colorButtonNormal for the disabled color and colorAccent for the enabled color.

```
    <Button
  ...
  style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />
```

If you want different colors than specified you can create a new theme and apply it to the button via `android:theme`. Then you can use this theme on all your buttons where you want same effect.

Comment: This question is about the native Android 5.0 implementation, not `appcompat-v7`. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Heisenberg I tried adding this but it doesn't add shadow on the image button. Any tips? I've tried using native ImageButton and AppCompatImageButton. Testing on 6.0.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem i thought was due to wrongly inflated layouts, but it appeared that adding `clipToPadding` did the trick.
This must be set to the parent `ViewGroup` containing the view you want to cast a shadow.

`...
android:clipToPadding="false"
...`

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for all the API versions of Android

Create a shadow `@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame` & if you want to customize the color of the background instead of white then create a layer-list background with customizable color on top of the shadow as shown below

Create a separate drawable file white_background_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--the shadow comes from here-->
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">

    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <!--whatever you want in the background, here i preferred solid white -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and use this drawable as the background like this

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
```