# Elevation not working for some elements

Tags: android, android-layout

Elevation does not seem to working for Buttons, and other elements.  I am using build tools 21.1.2 and target sdk is 21.  I am building for a 5.0 device.  The shadow appears for ImageButton but not for Button.  Any ideas?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button

Comment: thank you sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar