# Place ImageView over Button android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place an ImageView over a Button using RelativeLayout. Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFindDaysInBetween"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/blue_500"
                    android:text="@string/dt_text_days" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_find_days_in_between"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the image screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the ImageView's src image is not visible. However if i change the button at the back to an ImageView, the image of the top ImageView is visible. Please refer below..

Changed xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50" >

                <!-- 
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFindDaysInBetween"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/blue_500"
                    android:text="@string/dt_text_days" />
                -->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_find_days"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_find_days_in_between"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Changed xml's screenshot:

[image]

What is it that i am doing wrong in the first layout?

Comment: Use an ImageButton with a Text View to get the desired result.

Comment: Try setting this `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for button

Comment: Why not setting the Button's background?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher, i tried this, but no change in the result

Comment: @Tushar, my scenario is when the user clicks on the button, i will display the imageview on top of the button. So, setting the image as background for button is not what i need.

Comment: @VamsiChalla have you tried set `Button` background as transparent?

Comment: @Xcihnegn, I don't want the button to be transparent. I want to have a button with background and place ImageView over the button

Comment: I move my idea to answer

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The reason is actually *very* simple. :) We are so caught up thinking in 2D that we overlook the `elevation` - in Z.

There is nothing wrong with your first layout. The `Button` simply has a higher `elevation` than the `ImageView` - exactly `1dp` higher. Therefore, no matter how you arrange the two views, the `Button` rises above.

**A bit of proof**:

A Button, by default gets the `Widget.Material.Button` style:

```
<!-- Bordered ink button -->
<style name="Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_default_material</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="minWidth">88dip</item>
    <item name="stateListAnimator">@anim/button_state_list_anim_material</item>
    <item name="focusable">true</item>
    <item name="clickable">true</item>
    <item name="gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

The attribute that introduces this elevation is `android:stateListAnimator`. `StateListAnimator` is similar to `StateListDrawable`, and provides state change animations. The complete xml is here: [Link](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/button_state_list_anim_material.xml). But here's the base state of the button:

```
<!-- base state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                        android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                        android:valueTo="0"
                        android:startDelay="@integer/button_pressed_animation_delay"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                        android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
```

As you can see, the elevation value for the button is set to `@dimen/button_elevation_material`:

```
<dimen name="button_elevation_material">1dp</dimen>
```

And that's how the `ImageView` ends up being behind/below the `Button`.

**So, what can we do?**

A straight-forward solution would be to set the `ImageView's` elevation to the same amount - `1dp`.

Another solution, which will require a bit of work, is to remove the `Button's` elevation rather than change `ImageView's`. Based on the default `StateListAnimator`, we can create our own - and remove the elevation. Then, in your `res/values-v21/styles.xml`, define a style that inherits from `Widget.Material.Button`:

```
<style name="MyDepressedButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@anim/customized_state_animator</item>
</style>
```

Now, set this style on your `Button`:

```
<Button
    style="@style/MyDepressedButtonStyle"
    ....
    .... />
```

**Edit**:

Actually, we can apply the customized `StateListAnimator` directly:

```
<Button
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/customized_state_animator"
    ....
    .... />
```

No need to take the `scenic` route!

Comment: `elevation` is only available to Api 21 and higher so you can't use the "straight-forward" method

Comment: @BronDavies This whole issue is about API version  21 & up, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I had to set my elevation to 2dp in order for my view to overlap my button, but great explanation!

Comment: What do I put inside @anim/customized_state_animator ?

Comment: @DJTano https://gist.github.com/mwshubham/8e1012e2fdf05b618abd5bba5b72e34c#file-customized_state_animator-xml      Checkout my gist based on the answer.

Comment: thanks for the bit of proof. I was confused what's going on.

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution:
simply android:elevation="2dp"

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAccess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:background="@drawable/or"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp" />
```

Comment: Works for API level 21+

Comment: I also had to add translationZ

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's much easier to just set the StateListAnimator to @null

```
<Button
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@null" />
```

Source [Android 5.0 android:elevation Works for View, but not Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button)

Comment: Thank you. Elevating the ImageView doesn't help when the button is clicked, but this works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ImageButton` replace `Button` and set `ImageButton` background as transparent.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnFindDaysInBetween"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/blue_500_text"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"  
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_find_days_in_between"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle_white" />
```

You can make a image that has your blue_500 color and text(that is easy to create), then set this image to your `ImageButton`. After that, your `ImageView` will see on the top of `ImageButton`.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

Button is just a TextView with a certain style applied to it, so if you replace Button with TextView you can display an ImageView on top of it. This also works on API < 21.

Comment: This is the most valuable answer, in my opinion, because you can even set onClickListener() to textView and make it act like a Button

Answer (score 2):

`android:background` exists for all the view. As the name suggests this is what is going to be there in the background.

`android:src` exists for `ImageViews` and its subclasses. You can think of this as the foreground. Because `ImageView` is a subclass of View you even have `android:background` for that.

If the foreground is smaller than background, the background portion which is not covered by the foreground would be visible.
Also, you can use transparency in the foreground in which case the background would be visible(transparently).
You can use BACKGROUND FOR ALL THE VIEWS.. But You can use SRC only for `ImageView` & `ImageButton`.....

Comment: I understand what you are saying about android:src for ImageViews and ImageButtons, but what is it wrong in the first layout that the imageview is not visible?

Comment: I have checked your xml and it was working in my side. Which is the format of ic_check_circle_white.

Answer (score 2):

@Vamsi I tried your both combinations and first one is not working with `Button`. You have to go through `ImageView.` This is what I tried with with **ImageView**:

[image]

While I tried to do it with `Button` and see what was result:

[image]

I tried to change the order but all in vain! It seems you have to go with either `ImageView` or `ImageButton`.

At the end! You can see what I had tried:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!-- <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_web"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:text="@string/app_name" /> -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I had done same kind of work either with `ImageView` or `ImageButton` (probably with `ImageView`) and tried same approach as you were trying with `Button`.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah.. seems like button will be on top.. i am still looking at a definitive answer.. thanks for your time

Comment: No problem! It is always better to wait for some good solution rather messing your code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an ImageView on top of a Button, and you are developing for Android API < 21 (for instance, KitKat = 19), the easiest way is to not use a Button at all and use 2 ImageView instead.  Why would you want to do that?  May be because you defined a drawable shape to make the button look "cooler", so you are already using android:background with that shape.

Ex:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image01"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/desiredImageOnTop"
    />
```

Where @drawable/buttonshape.xml is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:radius="30dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerColor="#47A891"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />
</shape>
```

In that case, you should replace the Button with an ImageView, change android:background to android:src, and then, in the java code, you just add an OnClickListener as if it was a Button (both controls derive from View, and OnClickListener is a View event).  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, This is not an error, it is a simple design issues. I have been working on it for last 2 hours. And at last get an easy way.
Now, I want to share the code.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:paddingLeft="33dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
                    android:text="CHECK APPOINTMENT"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textSize="18sp"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/care_logo"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

It is working.

Answer (score -2):

I placed ImageView on a Button with a diversion of RelativeLayout, hope this helps.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/tempview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tempview"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tempview"
        android:src="@drawable/img_cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```