# Elevation not working for ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-elevation

Elevation for ImageView is not working. I declared ImageView in XML like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/youtube" />
```

What else should I do for elevation to work properly for ImageView?

Comment: it's working fine right?what is the problem?

Comment: edit your question with full xml file.

Comment: For any view android:elevation will   apply  only if the view has a android:background applied

Answer (score 43):

The elevation shadow is derived from the background drawable of a View. If your ImageView has no background, you'll see no shadow.

If you want to change that behavior, you need to build your own [`ViewOutlineProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) and call `View.setOutlineProvider()` to set it (and this is not trivial).

Comment: So, you can just add a background too.

Comment: @BladeCoder, What value need to set in outlineProvider, Is it background, bounds, paddedBounds or none

Comment: @Naveen Kumar M None, you need to extend the ViewOutlineProvider class and override the getOutline() method.

Comment: @BladeCoder, Okay Thanks!

Comment: Of course if you just want the shadow to fill the whole view, you can use BOUNDS or PADDED_BOUNDS.

Comment: Applying `android:outlineProvider="bounds"` is enough to see the shadow.

Comment: @BladeCoder would you please share some example how to add shadow effect to imageView , when background drawable  set to imageView .

Comment: Let me recap:
- If you want the shadow to follow the bounds of a translucent image, you need to set the image as background or provide a custom ViewOutlineProvider in code.
- If your image is fully opaque and has the same shape as your ImageView (rectangular), then you can use `android:outlineProvider="bounds"`

Answer (score 16):

For displaying a round Image with SHADOW with elevation attribute, I created a round drawable WITHOUT SHADOW as shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Use this drawable as background in your ImageView as shown below :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/center" />
```

This will display ImageView with shadow.

One question that might be arising in your mind is why to use xml drawable. As mentioned by other developers on various answers to this question, shadow is formed from background and a bordered background to be more specific.
Xml drawable helps us in creating a bordered background from which elevation attribute can create shadow.

Comment: Thank you, this was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 12):

**Works in all latest versions**

**Use CardView as parent layout.** Use `android:background="@drawable/your_img"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/your_img"` in ImageView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"        
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView       
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="@drawable/your_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what if image is circle ?

Comment: if the image is a circle and if you know the radius of the image, you can set app:cardCornerRadius to that value.

Comment: This produces a nasty bug in some Android 6 devices. The image is drawn in two steps: first, the image is drawn as a square and then it flickers and the image appears inside the CardView. And while you leave the screen, the CardView is lost and you see the image as a square again as soon as you press the back button.

My solution was to use Glide to make the image round and then apply a circular background, as @Tarun specifies in the answer below.

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to the clarification of [BladeCoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641080/1083957): applying `android:outlineProvider="bounds"` to the `ImageView` will result in the shadow to be displayed.

Comment: simple and easy. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CardView, be sure to leave the CardView background transparent.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/youtube" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

The elevation attribute will be simply ignored if your minSdk version is less than 21. Either change that or try the method explained over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28980908/7184172

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On `Lollipop` it works setting elevation. For `pre-Lollipop,` you need to implement shadows by yourself. `Support-v4` has `ViewCompat.setElevation(view, value)` method for by if you check the sources there is no implementation. (at least, at the time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using android:src you need to change to android:background for displaying shadows.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/youtube" />
```

Comment: How come I don't see any shadow? Tested on 5.1.1, with wrap_content for both width and height, and I've even tried android:outlineProvider="background" . Nothing shows elevation on the imageView's content.