# CardView with a smaller body and Image floating outside it

Tags: android, xml, cardview

I am trying to create a `CardView` in `Android` that would have the image look like it is floating outside the box and the `CardView` box covering it would look smaller.

Since I do not know how to better describe it I found a similar design and tried to draw it on `Paint`.

[image]

The confusing part for me is to make the box appear smaller than the actual `CardView` is.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30640745/1574250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try out this code (for your item's layout file):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView One"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView Two"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView Three"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note:** You must give more `elevation` to the `ImageView` that has to be placed above the `CardView` as because `CardView` has already got some its own elevation by default.

**In your build.gradle (Module: app) file, under the dependencies add these two dependencies as follows:**

```
dependencies {
    // For ConstraintLayout:
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    // For CardView:
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

**Screenshot (for the above code):**

*For screen size - 5.0 inch (1080 x 1920 pixels) [Device: Pixel 2]*

[image]

I hope, this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You should try a `FrameLayout` with the `CardView` and the `ImageView`. Then, give some margin to the `CardView` and you will get it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put the ImageView inside the CardView.

Try something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        />

    <CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:margin_top="8dp"
        android:margin_start="8dp">

            <!-- CardView contents -->
    </CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

You'll need to adjust the dimensions to suit your layout.

Comment: And what about the `"floating"` image?

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/cinza_claro"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/red_app_accent"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think you can do like this example, using margin to adjust the image.

[image: Example]