# How to place an image view over a button in layout for api levels below 21?

Tags: android, android-layout

In order to describe exactly what a button is meant for, I was trying to place a descriptive image over the button which is big enough to accommodate the image. I wanted the app to work for devices using api 20 and below. I went through the answers given at these two places

[elevation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640745/elevation-not-working-for-imageview/59310074#59310074) .
[placing imageview over button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560692/place-imageview-over-button-android)

The answer given at the second link does work for API levels 21 and above but not for those below because `item name="android:stateListAnimator"` does not seem to be directly accessible in them. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide your current impl in the form of layout and anything associated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is FrameLayout. FrameLayout children order is a Z order so You do something like:

```
 <FrameLayout>
    <Button>
    <ImageView>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Another way is to set the button background as the image of the image view.