# ImageButton over Button touch

Tags: android, button, touch, imagebutton

I have an small `ImageButton` placed on the top/right corner and a `Button` behind, wrapping all the content.

I think that the normal behaviour may be that when touch the small `ImageButton`, it receives the touch. But the current behaviour is that when it is touched, is like not existing, and passint the touch to the behind button.

I tried by using the `android:clickable` attribute, putting the small `ImageButton` in a `FrameLayout` also with `android:clickable="true"`, and a lot of other things.

Here is an image with the two elements selected, and the .xml. I think that it isn't really complex thing, but I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Thank you everyone.

[image: Selected elements]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/club_placeholder" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tab"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivBackground" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btFavorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_tab"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="Favorite"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your Button has higher elevation than the ImageButton. 
In fact, if you set a color to your background button, you will not see the favorite imageButton. So, changing your Button to ImageButton could solve the problem.

Check this link:  [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560692/place-imageview-over-button-android)

I hope this could help you ;)

Comment: Yes, the elevation is the solution. I added `android:elevation="1dp"` and  `android:elevation="2dp"` and it solved the wrong behaviour.

But, it works well in pre-lollipop devices? Android Studio doesn't give me any error.