# Android: Placing imageButton over a Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, imagebutton

I would like to place 2 small icons (with actions) over a big **Button** that take the 1/3 of the screen. The 2 icons and the button have to support actions when we click on them. I'm pretty sure I have to use **imageButton** for the icons. However I can't find any way to keep the icons (imageButton) on top of the button.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:onClick="action1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"           
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:onClick="action2"/>

    <com.myapp.CustomViews.myButton
        android:id="@+id/big_button1"
        android:text="@string/text_big_button1"
        android:background="@drawable/changing_button1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:onClick="bigAction1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The "@drawable/changing_button1" on the big Button allows me to put one color for the button and a different one when focused or pressed.

I tried so many different things and I couldn't find a way while I'm sure there is a simple solution. The icons remain hidden behind the big Button.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `I'm pretty sure I have to use imageButton for the icons` You can also use ImageViews or TextViews. It's jut to find the right trick to arrange your views in the RelativeLayout.

Comment: I could use ImageViews for the icons? And they can still have `android:onClick="action2"` ?
And it would work?

Comment: Sure. I often use ImageViews or TextViews as if they were Buttons. Just add the `android:clickable="true"` attribute.

Comment: But isn't there a problem with the elevation? Or the background attributes in my case?

Comment: Now, there's an EASY trick to do what you want. First place a dummy generic View (0dp in height and 0dp in width, invisible). And set it to the center (horizontal or both). Then place the other Views around it (to left, to right or to bottom) - And you're done!

Comment: I see. Like suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28980966/5175297

Comment: Yes, that's the general concept. Just adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try this and I will post the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it.
The solution is to use the `RelativeLayout` as a button and replace the `Button` by a simple `TextView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_changing_color"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:onClick="bigAction1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_buttons"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"           
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:onClick="action2"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"           
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:onClick="action3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about changing order in the layout ? Place your Button widget on top, then declare 2 icons after that ?

---

You should add `android:translationZ="5dip"` for the 2 `imageButton`. It works (you should run and see, it didn't appear so on the IDE)

Comment: You should add android:translationZ="5dip" for the 2 imageButton. It works (you should run and see, it didn't appear so on the IDE)

Comment: Yes but `android:translationZ` only works from API 21, and I need a lower one... :(

Thank you very much though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FrameLayout` to overlay views. For example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <com.myapp.CustomViews.myButton
        android:layout_gravitiy="center"
        .../>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravitiy="left|center_vertical"
        .../>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravitiy="right|center_vertical"  
        .../>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of your layout, which works fine.

I replaced all your custom stuff with plain android and standard buttons, and moved the big button up in the layout, because if it is at the bottom, it has a higher z-index and overlays the two small buttons.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/big_button1"
        android:text="BIG BUTTON"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:onClick="bigAction1"/>    

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/icon1"
            android:text="BT1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="action1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:text="BT2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="action2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```