# Overlap an image view on button in a constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to design a layout that has one image view on the side but overlaps the button. I have to do this in **constraint layout**.
Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

attached is the design below:[design needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS07k.jpg)

Edit: I tried how the second answer told me to do. But still, the image is hidden by the button. So can anyone suggest a way to make the image visible on top of the button?

[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3gIt.jpg)

login_layout

```
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopLogin"
            android:background="@drawable/round_cornered_top_white_bg_drawable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etUsername"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.50" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="name"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/etPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSubmit" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/imgTogglePassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/btn_toggle_password"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/etPassword" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:background="@color/purple_700"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_ico_gonext"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btnSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btnSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your `ImageView`. `btnLogin` is id of your button id, Add parent in top and bottom constraints to align imageview vertically center.

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

> Edit:

Overlap image on button using one `ConstraintLayout`, You need to add `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`, but using this all elevation and translationZ will not be display to Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:background="@color/purple_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btnSubmit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btnSubmit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output for above code:

[image]

For more info regarding adding elevation and overlap views, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560692/place-imageview-over-button-android)

Comment: do you have a way of using just one constraint layout to make this layout?

Comment: @Kiran Please check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `ImageView`'s top and bottom constraints to the top and bottom of the `Button` (which basically centres it vertically) and the same for the `end` constraint (or `right` if it's specifically meant to always be on the right, even in RTL layouts) to position it at the end. Add margin as appropriate.

But really in this case you probably just want to add an icon to the button:

```
<Button
    ...
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_next"
    app:iconGravity="end"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
/>
```

(rundown of the attributes [here](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button))

Comment: Do check my question again. I have implemented as you mentioned in your answer but now the button overlaps the image view. Can you help?

Comment: @Kiran try giving the icon an elevation (``android:elevation``), ``2dp`` might work but check the button doesn't elevate above it when you press it. Again, you probably just want to add an icon to the button itself, it provides that functionality and avoids weird behaviour!

Comment: Actually, the image needs to have a different background color than the buttons so I am adding an image view over the button.