# How to add shadow to the FAB provided with the android support design library?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-design-library, android-appcompat

The title is pretty self explaining.

The following code does not render shadow below the Floating Action Button. What can be done to render shadow? Is this feature really not supported even on API 21+?

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Note: Adding `android:elevation` does not add shadow on API 21.

[image: Example screenshot]

Screenshot taken from the example by dandar3:
https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design

Comment: At least for 21+, this may apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button

Comment: Something I considered, but removing the StateListAnimator does not bring back shadow. This may be due to the fact that the FAB is actually an extended ImageView not a Button. Strange because FAB actually has a StateListAnimator.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Simply setting `app:borderWidth="0dp"` resolve this issues for me.

**Note:** don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root layout.

This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067) should be fixed in next release of android design library.

Comment: Wow, that actually works... strange behavior. I can't imagine that this is expected behavior.

Comment: @Thorinside this is bug, a square bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067

Answer (score 35):

For API 21+ you need to set `app:borderWidth="0dp"` and `app:elevation="[number]dp"`. Setting elevation you are giving the size of shadow that you want:

[image: Example of values for parameter "elevation"]

Here is an example of code for API 21+:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/locate_user_FAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/location_off"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/take_taxi_FAB"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentGrey">
```

One important thing to remember for APIs below to 21 (Android 4), is for terms of compatibility FAB will put a margins around your button to draw the shadow. Then you should do something like that (I'm currently using this code and works):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/locate_user_FAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/location_off"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/take_taxi_FAB"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/map_FAB_marginRight"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/locate_user_FAB_marginBottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentGrey">
```

I prefer to put `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` at the beginning of the XML, but I put there just to remind you ;]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm setting the FAB above Map view and the fcking shadow doesn't appear on my FAB

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing this same issue and I got it to work by deleting this tag from my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

I initially added it, together with `android:largeHeap="true"`, because I thought I needed it for a HeatMap in which a large number of points where shown, but then I realized it could work just with `android:largeHeap="true"`.

Answer (score 5):

If this still isn't working for some, there is a significant difference between:

```
app:elevation="6dp"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

and

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
app:elevation="6dp"
```

Order seems to matter for some reason (The first order works, second doesn't) and this is from the support library 23.3.0

Answer (score 5):

Check manifest in project or libraries in Application tag and **delete** them

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

But if you need these options then shadows and transformation animations will not work

Answer (score 0):

In case it help, I was using

```
android:tint="@color/myColor"
```

instead of

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/myColor".
```

Replacing tint by backgroundTint brought back the shadow.