# FAB on pre-lollipop devices with the new support lib

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-design-library

The [support library doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) states that the version 22.2 supports FloatingActionButton on Pre-Lollipop devices.

I have implemented a demo app to show a FAB on KitKat. 
The FAB is shown but I still can't set the elevation neither in the xml nor in the code.
In the xml I get the warning and I need to use `tools:ignore="NewApi"`. If I call `setElevation` programmatically I get an exception because the method does not exist.

I have added this to my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    style="@style/FAB"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_ringtone" />
```

where the style is defined like this:

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="FAB" tools:ignore="NewApi">
       <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/fab_width</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/fab_height</item>
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_background</item>
       <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
       <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/fab_margin</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/fab_margin</item>
       <item name="android:elevation" >@dimen/fab_elevation</item>
       <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@anim/rise</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

What should I do to set the elevation on KitKat with the new support library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the new FAB is now part of the support library, you'll probably need to replace

```
<item name="android:elevation">@dimen/fab_elevation</item>
```

by

```
<item name="app:elevation">@dimen/fab_elevation</item>
```

in your style.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532863/how-to-add-shadow-to-the-fab-provided-with-the-android-support-design-library#30539065.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

In the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

In the layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    style="@style/FAB"
    app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_ringtone" />
```

In the styles.xml under values folder:

```
<style name="FAB">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/fab_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/fab_size</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/fab_edge_distance</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/fab_edge_distance</item>
```

In the styles.xml under values-21 folder:

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="FAB" tools:ignore="NewApi">
       <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/fab_width</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/fab_height</item>
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_background</item>
       <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
       <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/fab_margin</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/fab_margin</item>
       <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@anim/rise</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: notice that I didn't manage to set the android:stateListAnimator yet