# How to remove FloatingActionButton's surrounding shadow?

Tags: android, shadow, floating-action-button

I'm trying to replace the third party [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) with [the native one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) which is packaged in library `com.android.support:design:22.2.0`.The default look has a dark shadow around the image,How can I get rid of it? I know the former one provides with the method `setShadow()`,but I just can't find similar one from the latter.

[image]

This is the related XML layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/alarm_front"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_icon_alarm_notset" />
```

And I have set its background color to yellow.

```
mAlarmBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.floatButtonColor)));
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Override the default [elevation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:elevation) of the FAB by adding:

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Or in code call [View.setElevation(float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation%28float%29)

Comment: setElevation is available at a minimum API level of 21,how can it work below LOLLIPOP?

Comment: You could simply stick with the old approach of creating your own ImageButton on pre-lollipop. As you did before they introduced FAB

Comment: Other developers are reporting issues with shadows on the new support FAB, although generally that the shadow is not showing which is the opposite problem, but maybe a related issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532863/how-to-add-shadow-to-the-fab-provided-with-the-android-support-design-library

Comment: Then I would stick with the third party until there is a solution to the FAB of the design library.Thanks BrentM.

Comment: With the official FAB, you can use `app:elevation="0dp"` to do what you want. I tried on Android 4.1.1 and it works fine. I don't know if there is a Java solution yet.

Comment: @Gaëtan, you should turn this to an answer, It really helped me. thanks

Comment: use `app:elevation="0dp"` for compatibility

Answer (score 39):

Add this

`android:elevation="0dp" 
 app:elevation="0dp"`

It's will be like :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: This is the answer among all

Answer (score 26):

Override the default elevation of the FAB by adding the following:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 8):

Make borderWidth to 0

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

Comment: Tried all of the above, but the shadows kept... This answer worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the support libraries - the latest Android Studio templates us them.
Check the imports

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//if using support app compat
fab.setCompatElevation(16.0f);
```

else if youre only supporting newer sdk versions

```
fab.setElevation();
//call requires SDK 21
```

see

```
.../app/build.gradle
  minSdkVersion 18    << less than 21 so req support libraries
  targetSdkVersion 25
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried all suggestions above and nothing has worked for API 23 and higher. I've ended up with this, which has completely removed the shadow:

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

Below is how my button looks like now:

[image]

Before the change it looked as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This solutions works for ExtendedFloatingActionButton, too:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
```