# No elevation For FloatingActionButton ( FAB ) in Support Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library) I built a Floating Action Button to add elements to my Listview

The code is easy:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/spg_rosa"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

The thing is

```
app:elevation="4dp"
```

is not working, I can't see any shadow!

I grab the icon from Google : https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Any idea?

EDIT: I'm using it in Samsung S3 Mini ( API 16 )

Comment: Strange, most people report that adding app:borderWidth="0dp" fixes the issue, you already have that. It may be worthwhile waiting for the fix for this issue in the next update of the design support library. Also, it may help someone answer if you mention what API version exhibits this issue for you. See this post for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532863/how-to-add-shadow-to-the-fab-provided-with-the-android-support-design-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested your sample on a Samsung S3 Mini (API 16).
For me the elevation works. 
because the elevation value is so small it's not very visible, try to increase the value. As BrentM says the elevation is not working if `app:borderWidth="0dp"` is not added.

Comment: I already tried to increase this value... If it works for you, it must something else... Thanks for your help, I will keep searching!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", that means your button is right at the bottom edge, try adding at least 10dp of margin at the bottom and it will fix your problem.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/spg_rosa"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
```

Regards!

Comment: This helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thing was My Listview were black!
I changed color theme to white, and I could see the shadow !