# Extra padding around Floating Action Button Android

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

[image]

I am trying to make a profile page in Android. I am using a floating action Button to display user picture.

Initially i want to display a default picture.

My xml code goes like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/userIcon"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/male_icon"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
```

My question is why there is some extra space around the FAB. Cant i remove that space/padding?

**EDITED:**

here is my full xml code::

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:contentScrim="#2678AD"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/userIcon"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/male_icon"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
```

Comment: you can give margins like:android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

Answer (score 6):

u might want to change the scaletype attribute to center. Like,

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the extra padding by allowing your icon to be larger in size. This way you can set the icon to be the size of the floating action button.

```
    app:maxImageSize="40dp"
```

or whatever size you want to give it.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

and you can also remove shadow using elevation

```
app:elevation="6dp"
```

see this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532863/how-to-add-shadow-to-the-fab-provided-with-the-android-support-design-library)

if its not working then try to manage outline shadow like this:

```
Button fab = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabbutton);

    Outline mOutlineCircle;
    int shapeSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.shape_size);
    mOutlineCircle = new Outline();
    mOutlineCircle.setRoundRect(0, 0, shapeSize, shapeSize, shapeSize / 2);

    fab.setOutline(mOutlineCircle);
    fab.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Comment: Hey @sagar, Thanks for the reply but that didnt help!

Comment: I tested on android 5.1.1 too. Same result :|

Comment: and make sure you are using latest version of design dependency

Answer (score 1):

In layout file set attribute elevation to 0. because it takes default elevation.

```
 app:elevation="0dp"
```

Now in activity check api level greater than 21 and set elevation if needed.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        fabBtn.setElevation(10.0f);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using opposite `app:fabSize="normal"` . Change to `app:fabSize="mini"`

Comment: Thanks, it was perfect for my requirement. also it would be good to mention ```app:fabCustomSize="your custom fab size"``` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is margin, not padding. Try to do it programmatically:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) floatingActionButton.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); 
        floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Or try to put FloatingActionButton into CoordinatorLayout, like an example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Huy, Tried solving it pragmatically but didnt help. And the FAB is within a coordinate layout

Comment: pls post your full of xml, dimens value :)

Comment: Have you try to use `android:scaleType="center"`?

set layout width and height to wrap_content and added the fabsize attribute.