# Floating Action Button no shadow showing

Tags: java, android, shadow, floating-action-button, elevation

I am trying to get a shadow under my Floating action button but its not showing.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleX="-1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="21dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white" />

<Custom View/>
```

This is how it shows now:
[image: No shadow fab]

What am i doing wrong?

Edit 1: The suggested fix to add app:borderWidth="0dp" doesn't fix my problem

Edit 2: Problem solved apparently using     android:scaleX="-1" removes the shadow

Comment: already answered - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30752754/5049244

Answer (score 1):

you need to just add  `app:borderWidth="0dp"` to your `FloatingActionButton`

**Sample code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="21dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white" />
```

and make sure

Check manifest file in Application tag and delete them

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

But if you need these options then shadows and transformation animations will not work

Comment: I already added borderwith to my xml. There is a duplicate now is there something im not seeing? It gives me an error when i copy it into my android studio :(

Comment: @Flab98 check  this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177054/7666442

Comment: @Flab98 check updated ans

Comment: These tags are not in my manifest file

Comment: Fixed thx for the help