# Floating Action Buttons over Drawer Menu

Tags: android, xml

I have added 2 floating action buttons to my activity. The problem is that I also have a drawer menu and when I open it my floating buttons remain visible.
This is how my XML file looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            ></include>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="#FF8845"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="#AF3800"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView5"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="270dp"></ListView>
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_friend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_friend"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_user_photos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_photos"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is how they look like:
[image][image]

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: did you try setting the elevation of the drawer to 16dp and the one for fabs at 6 dp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set visibility of buttons GONE or INVISIBLE in onDrawerOpened(View view) listener.

Answer (score 1):

Move floating buttons declaration in XML to the top of `CoordinatorLayout` container (before the `DrawerLayout` declaration). Android draws views from top to bottom.

UPD.
As suggested by @JohanShogun, `elevation` might be the key. FABs probably have default `elevation` value higher than you have in your `DrawerLayout`. Try to override it with lower value and if it won't help, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button/27112143#27112143).

Comment: Consider that this may not always be true on lollipop as some views (such as cards) have a default elevation.