# Difference in appearance of Button and ImageButton

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop, imagebutton

I just noticed that the borders of the Button and the ImageButton look different. The ImageButton is totally flat. I cannot explain it and I would like to have the ImageButton as "3d-ish" as the default Button. Any ideas are welcome!

This is my xml-code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Power"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/f_light_on"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how it looks on my Lollipop tablet:
[image]

Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Comment: you want the ImageButton with border?

Comment: Have you tried to add `style:android:attr/buttonStyle`

Comment: Its best you create a style in the drawable folder and set android:background = "@drawable/your_xml" to keep it consistent

Comment: You are free to design your own 9 patch with a "3d-ish" look.

Comment: Thanks for down voting :( In my opinion it is a very inconsistent behavior. I'm asking myself why two buttons with the only difference that the one contains a text and the other an image look different.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button` has default elevation (actually, it has a [`StateListAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html) that provides elevation when the button is enabled) under the Material theme, whereas `ImageButton` does not.

Comment: thank you! this clarifies the behavior, although it doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: `ImageButton` is often used with a null background, which doesn't lend itself to setting an elevation. We opted for breaking as few apps as possible when designing the Material widget styles.