# Is there a way to create an emulator with XXXHDPI density on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to test my work on XXXHDPI device. Instead of buying one, is it possible to use Android Studio Emulator to make one? Currently I see the all density is there from ldpi to xxhdpi, but not xxxhdpi.

p/s: Actualy I have a an S7 device which is XXXHDPI, but wanted another to confirm some behavior is specific to XXXHDPI as per question in [Where did my 10dp height button goes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164170/where-did-my-10dp-height-button-goes?noredirect=1#comment61864139_37164170).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an emulator of **Nexus 6** or **Nexus 6P**. They have a density of 3.5, which is XXXHDPI.

[Reference](https://design.google.com/devices/)

Comment: Thanks. What about density of 4.0? Like Samsung S7. Is it still consider XXXHDPI?