# Why ProgressBar on top of the Button is visible only when Button is disabled?

Tags: android, android-button, android-progressbar, android-framelayout

I have a Button and a ProgressBar inside a FrameLayout. How come my ProgressBar is visible only when Button is disabled? I'm running my app on android 6.0.1.

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_love"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Love" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Because it is hiding behind button because button's width is match_parent which takes full width of layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should increase the elevation of the `ProgressBar`. You will find the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112143/321106).