# android:elevation doesn't show shadows

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, kotlin

I have a question. 
Why `android:elevation` doesn't show shadows? I am making shadows first time

Only used in `ImageButton` it's working (when I use with android:background it isn't working)

[image: my_image]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
        android:text="TestBTT"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:background="@drawable/przycisk"
        android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"/>
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton" android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp" android:cropToPadding="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
<TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:elevation="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="196dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

What to do to make the shadows appear under the button?
And what to do to show up under the button where is android: background?

Comment: post code for **przycisk** also. or is there any image?

Comment: You might need to put `android:clipToPadding="false"` on all of  them and also set `android:clipChildren="false", android:clipToPadding="false"` on the parent container

Answer (score 0):

> The default `Button` style under `Material` has a `StateListAnimator`
>   that controls the `android:elevation` and `android:translationZ`
>   properties.

<sub>[copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112143/1843331)</sub>

just add this property to your `Button`. you can set your own using the `android:stateListAnimator` property.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

**full code :**

```
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/my_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:translationZ="2dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="BUTTON">
```

**UpDate :**

for Understanding I set it 10dp..

**xml code :**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:translationZ="10dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="BUTTON"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's working, but when I use `android:background="@drawable/przycisk"` in my Button,  I haven't shadow

Comment: przycisk is a image